# Obtain different range after applying rotation in scipy.ndimage

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy

I have a random matrix `A` in range of [0,3]. I will apply rotate with the angle of 10 for the matrix. However, I got the different range in the rotated matrix. What is wrong in my code? Thanks

```
from scipy.ndimage import rotate
import numpy as np
A = np.random.randint(0, 4, size=(64,128,128))
print (A.max(), A.shape)
B=rotate(A, angle=10, reshape=False, axes=(0,1))
print (B.max(), B.shape)
```

Output is

```
(3, (128, 128, 128))
(4, (128, 128, 128))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scipy.ndimage.rotate` ([manual](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.ndimage.rotate.html#scipy.ndimage.rotate)) performs matrix rotation using spline interpolation and by default uses the spline order of 3, which may cause an output value to become larger than the input data.

You could reduce the order of the used spline interpolation to 1, which changes the behavior to linear interpolation. To do this, modify the rotate line as follows:

```
B=rotate(A, angle=10, order=1, reshape=False, axes=(0,1))
```

For more information about spline interpolation, see this [introductory paper](https://www.math.uh.edu/~jingqiu/math4364/spline.pdf).

Comment: Could you fix it? or suggest other solution

Comment: Thanks. It worked well. I find another way that is `prefilter=False` (`order=3`). Do you think it is correct

Comment: I believe that specifying `prefilter=False` will just skip an internal call to `spline_filter()` and eventually produce incorrect output, if you have not prefiltered your input data properly. I'd stick with `order=1`.